# Java NetworkInterface.getInetAddresses() returns raw Ip address in MAC OSX

Tags: java

I am using NetworkInterface.getInetAddresses()in java.net to get the local hostname and ip address. I am getting the Exception "Host name is raw IP address" in MAC OSX as it is retuning in raw IP address. Where as it works fine in windows (Returns DNS hostname). Do i need to make any configuration changes to get the correct result in MAC?

```
 NetworkInterface netInterface = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost());
            Enumeration addresses = netInterface.getInetAddresses();
            while (addresses.hasMoreElements()) {
                InetAddress addr = (InetAddress) addresses.nextElement();
                String hostName = addr.getHostName();
                String ipAddress = addr.getHostAddress();
                // If host name is raw IP address in a string format then throw exception.
                if(hostName.equals(ipAddress)){
                    throw new Exception("Host name is raw IP address; domain="+domain);
                }
//                 If the host name is qualified, determine the raw host name.
                int period = hostName.indexOf('.');
                if (period >= 0) {
                    hostName = hostName.substring(0, period);
                }
                localHosts.add(hostName.toLowerCase(Locale.US));
            }
```